# MacVim as ODB Editor

Tags: macos, macvim

How do I configure MacVim as an ODB Editor in Mac OS X?  I have Lion (10.7), but I imagine it's the same for Snow Leopard.  This process seems to be missing from both the MacVim documentation and a simple Google search, although MacVim's website clearly states that MacVim has ODB Editor support.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found one blog post about it from long ago that references a part of the preferences menu that no longer exists.  http://deflexion.com/2008/03/using-macvim-almost-everywhere-in-mac

Also, the +odbeditor flag shows up in `:version`, but the documentation for macvim only states:

> ```
>                   *odbeditor* *external-editor*
> ```
>
> MacVim can act as an 'external editor' for Mac OS X applications that support the ODB Editor Protocol
>   (or the 'external editor' protocol).  Each application has different
>   ways of configuring this option, check the application's
>   documentation.  Once configured properly MacVim can be used to open
>   files in such an application.
>
> A technical note: MacVim handles file open, modified and closed
>   events.  In the open event the FTok and Burl parameters are parsed
>   (the latter is ignored at the moment though).  In the modified and
>   closed events the Tokn parameter is sent back to the server
>   application.

Which is close, but seems to fail to mention how exactly to make it work.